# Bash script with grep -w

Tags: macos, bash, grep

I am using the following command: x.txt | grep -w 'in'
and I am getting answers like:
in
into
... etc.

I only want the answer:
in

How should i modify the command?

Comment: You should rephrase your original question to specify that the problem has to do with UTF-8 specific characters. Also, look at "EDIT4" in my answer below where I use `sed` to work around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, the command should be

```
grep -w in x.txt
```

Your current pipe doesn't work, and it is unnecessary to `cat` the file just to pipe it. `grep` can read files directly.

Second, the `-w` does exactly what you want. From the man page:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select only those lines containing matches  that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

`grep` will return the *complete lines* where the word occurs though; that is the function of `grep`; I mention it to check that you don't get confused because of that.

If you *just* want to return the word, as you say, you can do

```
grep -ow in x.txt
```

since `-o` returns only the matching part, but that seems quite unfruitful. *What are you really trying to do?*

---

**EDIT:** An explicit example:

```
$ cat test
word in word
within word
word word
$ grep -w in test
word in word
```

"within" is not matched.

**EDIT2:** Another example:

```
$ grep '\<in\>' test 
word in word
```

**EDIT3:** It was given that the problem was with Swedish characters. I can reproduce this, even with the environment variable `LANG` set to `sv_SE.UTF-8`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260293/egrep-accented-characters-not-recognised-as-part-of-a-word suggests using Perl for UTF-8 specific tasks as the easiest solution.

---

**EDIT4:** It seems I can use `sed` to get this working with Swedish characters:

```
$ cat test
word den word
avträden word
word word
$ sed -n '/\bden\b/p' test
word den word
$ sed -n '/\<den\>/p' test
word den word
```

It is a pragmatic solution, but hopefully it works for this task.

Comment: What I meant was that I only want the line where the complete word is present, i.e. a line where "in" is present but not a line where "within" is present.

Comment: Yes, but that is **exactly** what `-w` does. Does it not work?  Give an explicit example where it does not work. I did a test case just now, and it works just as you want, from all I can tell.

Comment: grep -w "den" ./sv_enb.txt gives the result den;it
avträden;privies
(I am using OSX)

Comment: OSX could very well be relevant. Have you looked at the manual for `grep` on your system? Is `-w` described? Otherwise, you can exchange `-w in` for `'\<in\>'`, as was trying to be described in the now deleted answer. It could also be some strange unicode error on OSX, but try the above first.

Comment: grep "\<den\>" ./sv_enb.txt gives den;it
avträden;privies. When I read the man pages they are the same as other man pages for grep, no special information about the command in OSX (or OpenBSD).

Comment: @NewBo: Post a minimal text file in your original question which exhibits the behavior you say.

Comment: I am new in this forum and can't seem to find how to add a file. However, it's a UTF-8 txt file with the following two lines (to give you an exmaple): den;it
avträden;privies and the command is as the samples I gave above. Could it be the Swedish characters?

Comment: @NewBo: Yes, it sounds like it treats the `ä` as a word delimiter. It is most likely a UTF-8 issue. The easiest fix is probably to abandon `grep` for Perl in this case.